# how to display the intersect of two columns with the corresponding date?

Tags: r, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

The three columns are date,secondpage and exit page.
i want to display the common values in secondpage column and exitpage column with the correponding date.

I have used intersect(col1,col2)
but i want to display the date also.

**date**-----------**secondpage**--------------**exitpage**
27/09--------- homepage-------------------homepage
28/09----------landingpage-----------------homepage
29/09----------contactus--------------------aboutus
30/09----------aboutus----------------------aboutus

**I need the OUTPUT as**

**date**-----------**secondpage**------------- **exitpage**
27/09--------- homepage------------------ homepage
30/09----------aboutus---------------------- aboutus

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272

Comment: Do you mean something like `x[ x$secondPagePath == x$exitPagePath, ]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using `data.table`

I have first generated the example data

```
dt<-data.table("date" = c("27/09","28/09","29/09","30/09"),
               "secondpage" = c("homepage","landingpage","contactus","aboutus"),
               "exitpage" = c("homepage","homepage","aboutus","aboutus"))

> dt
    date  secondpage exitpage
1: 27/09    homepage homepage
2: 28/09 landingpage homepage
3: 29/09   contactus  aboutus
4: 30/09     aboutus  aboutus
```

The following code should give you the desired output

```
dt_res<-dt[secondpage == exitpage]

> dt_res
    date secondpage exitpage
1: 27/09   homepage homepage
2: 30/09    aboutus  aboutus
```

The alternative, without using data table would be

```
dt_res<-dt[dt$secondpage == dt$exitpage,]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: From the `data.table` solution, the use of `.(date,secondpage,exitpage)` is unnecessary since all columns are returned by default. In the base solution, `which` is completely unnecessary.